# How to apply WebSocket as a provider in WebRTC?

Tags: flutter, webrtc

I have a question for you.
I'm implementing a video call function using WebRTC, and it worked normally in the demo app (single page) for implementing the function. (It works normally in the same network or other network environments.)

The problem is that in the environment of the first screen [user list] -> the second screen [video call screen], it works normally only in the same network situation. The difference from the demo app project above is that WebSocket is managed through a provider. In this environment, video call connection is not made in other network situations, but only in the same network situation.

I don't know if the above problem is a problem caused by using a WebSocket Provider, or if this is a problem, why it works normally in the same network situation.

In my Flutter project, I want video calls to run well on different networks.
Currently, connections are made only under the same network conditions.

Comment: You are using stun server for video call in webrtc. if you want to connect with different  network you have to configure TURN server.[https://webrtc.org/getting-started/turn-server]

Comment: Map<String, dynamic> configuration = {
      "iceServers": [
        {"url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"},
        {
          "urls": "turn:webrtc.___turnserverName.com",
          "username": "********",
          "credential": "********",
        },
      ],
      "iceTransportPolicy": "relay"
    };
 yes, I Know, And Use these servers, but not working

Comment: okay please try this once,When you send candidate to other user put 1000 mili second of delay after that add this candidate

Comment: I'll let you know the situation again.
"iceServers": [
{"url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"},{
"urls": "turn:webrtc.****.com","username": "****","credential": "********",},],"iceTransportPolicy": "relay"};
I am using the STUN server, TURN, and relay server as above. If you remove the STUN and relay server and run it, the screen will come out well. But in the same environment, other demo apps can run well even if they're included, but when you move to an existing project, it doesn't work. We are currently experimenting in an Android, the content settings of AndroidManifest are the same.

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much!!! I solve the problem.. your help answer!! – 
My Problem is not Provider and 2 PageMovement 
problem is occured when ice-candidate changing!! 
So, I adguset to delay 1 second when handleIce function, Thank you very! Much!! happy !!